# Errors When Making a Stripe Charge using Custom cURL and PHP Code

Tags: php, api, curl, stripe-payments

After doing 3 days of solid research and trying my absoloute best to resolve the issue in hand, Ive become to the point of no success and have had to realise maybe this is something i should have not tried to attempt! On Failing with my own personal attempts i have had to turn to you experts in need of some advice and help along my beginner learning stage.

I have tried to use the PHP code supplied by stripe however due to the complex custom form we use in our website and also alot of our website traffic comes internally we need a way to send payments to stripe easiser than integrating a whole new php payment process that can handle the payments from internal clients as well so i thought i knew a little cURL due to using several cURL and PHP API Calls already within the website process.

The cURL i have tried for stripe is as follows:

---

```
    $headers = array(
    'Authorization: Bearer sk_test_my_test_key_here',
);
$ch = curl_init("https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges -H Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded -u sk_test_my_test_key: -d source[object]=card -d source[number]=4242424242424242 -d source[exp_month]=08 -d source[exp_year]=18 -d source[cvc]=123 -d amount=250 -d currency=gbp -d description=Testing ");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;
curl_close($ch);
```

---

{ "error": { "type": "invalid_request_error", "message": "Unrecognized request URL (POST: /v1/charges%20-H%20Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded%20-u%20sk_test_keyP:%20-d%20source[object]=card%20-d%20source[number]=4242424242424242%20-d%20source[exp_month]=08%20-d%20source[exp_year]=18%20-d%20source[cvc]=123%20-d%20amount=250%20-d%20currency=gbp%20-d%20description=Testing). Please see https://stripe.com/docs or we can help at https://support.stripe.com/." } }

---

I have tried to read up on the documentation, but nothing explains about the errors i get, I think the biggest part of the problem is im not experienced enough to know exactly what to research and the key-phrases experts like you would know to look up.

---

i have tried with and without the `-H Content-Type included`and still get the same issue however if i was to copy and paste the curl into the command line and execute it from a command using

```
curl.exe https://...................
```

then the message is successful and i get the response i want back to say the card has been charged.

```
also tried  `$string = rawurlencode($data) and then http_build_query` on the $string
```

Here is enough example i have tried:

```
<?php
$headers = array(
    'Authorization: Bearer sk_test_removed_for_stackoverflow',
);

// create curl resource 
$ch = curl_init(); 

// set url 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges -u sk_test_removed: -d source[object]=card -d source[number]=4242424242424242 -d source[exp_month]=08 -d source[exp_year]=18 -d source[cvc]=123 -d amount=250 -d currency=gbp -d description=Test ");
```

also tried it like this:

```
// set url 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges -u sk_test_removed: -d source[object]=$card -d source[number]=$number -d source[exp_month]=$expdate -d source[exp_year]=$expmonth -d source[cvc]=$ccv -d amount=$amount -d currency=gbp -d description=$sale "); 

// set headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

//return the transfer as a string 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

// $output contains the output string 
$output = curl_exec($ch); 
print($output);

// close curl resource to free up system resources 
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

I am now honestly at a lost end, I would be extreamly greatfull for anyone to be able to assist me and help me on this issue, After 3 hard painfull days i really don't know what to do.

As a novice learner it is very hard knowing exactly what to search for when doing re-search on the issues. I have spent 3 days on google with 2 warning messages saying they think i was sending automated query's as a result of how many times if done research!! So any advice and help really would go a long way on this.

Thanks All.

Comment: Try using `POST_FIELDS`

Comment: Hi Scott, as appose to:  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS   do you mean to use:   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST_FIELDS  ?  Thanks

Comment: yup that's the one. Use the post fields and pass the post vars as an array. Might do the trick

Comment: I did actually try it like an array but no joy, Can you provide an answer as to the way you would assume scott?  Here is my previous array attempt:  $data = array("source[object]"=>"card", 
"source[number]"=>"4242424242424242", 
"source[exp_month]"=>"08", 
"source[exp_year]"=>"18",
"source[cvc]"=>"123",
"amount"=>"250",
"currency"=>"gbp");

$string = http_build_query($data);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is using the [Stripe PHP bindings](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php) not a possible solution? It would be much simpler:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_...");

// Token creation. In production this should be done client-side via Stripe.js or Checkout.
$token = \Stripe\Token::create([
  "card" => array(
    "number" => "4242424242424242",
    "exp_month" => 8,
    "exp_year" => 18,
    "cvc" => "123"
  )
]);

// Charge creation
try {
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
      "amount" => 250,
      "currency" => "gbp",
      "source" => $token->id,
      "description" => "Testing"
    ]);
} catch(...) {
    // Handle possible failures. See https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#errors
}
```

If you really insist on going with curl, this should work:

```
$apiKey = 'sk_test_...';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges",
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        "Authorization: Bearer " . $apiKey
    ],
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query([
        "amount" => 250,
        "currency" => 'gbp',
        "source" => array(
            "object" => "card",
            "number" => "4242424242424242",
            "exp_month" => 8,
            "exp_year" => 18,
            "cvc" => "123"
        ),
        "description" => "Testing"
    ])
]);
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Notes:

1. Providing the card details yourself, without client-side tokenization via [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js) or [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout), raises the problem of [PCI compliance](https://support.stripe.com/questions/do-i-need-to-be-pci-compliant-what-do-i-have-to-do), but I assume you're aware of that.
2. Using the bindings makes it much easier to handle charge creation failures, via exceptions. See [the documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#errors) for more information.

Comment: Excellent post Ywain i apprecaite the help.  The top PHP script would you be able to use that as it is and set the array values as variables for example:  "number" => $ccnum, and so on... The above script will execute on the processing page along with other api calls, the processing page will waiting for the response from stripe and then if approved redirect to success and if failed or declined will take the user back to the payment page with the displayed error message. Will that be possible using the php bindings and the above sample?

Comment: The Curl Request works perfect, If possible Ywain could you help me to get the top option working with the php binarys as i would prefer to make sure we are 100% compliant than have any legal issues!  Thanks a lot for taking your time to help me, I hope we can get the php option to work :)

Comment: Hi NewLearner! The simplest way to use the Stripe PHP bindings is to use Composer (see the [GitHub page](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php#composer)). I also edited my answers with a few more details and links. Let me know if you want more information!

Comment: @Ywain very good answer, Hope you both get the outcome you need.

Comment: Ywain, I am currently trying to get it to work now so i will get back to you as soon as possible, As it stands at the moment i can not get the php section to create a token then process it on by charging. i get no errors but a blank white screen as using a custom form so the processing page will deal with the handling of the token create and charge.

Comment: @NewLearner: if you have lots of questions as you progressively integrate Stripe, you should join the IRC channel #stripe on freenode. Stripe engineers and enthusiasts will happily give you a hand :)

Answer (score -2):

```
1 step :
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/stripe-debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">



Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_gETzDYx9EWwlU5ZQYvU78OWv');
</script>


          <form action="" method="POST">


<script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_gETzDYx9EWwlU5ZQYvU78OWv"
    data-amount="895367"
    data-name="GMR"
    data-description="98000.00"
    data-image="https://d1p3fwm9yfjbr.cloudfront.net/home-pagenew/images/gmr_logo.jpg"
    data-locale="auto">
  </script>
</form>


2nd step :








function curl_stripe($parameters){
            $username="sk_test_TmbzPtTg1KVJz6Y87D0nwaUJ"; 
            $password= "";
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$path);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1024); //timeout after 30 seconds
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"amount=".$parameters['amount']."&currency=usd&source=".$parameters['token']."&metadata[order_id]=".$parameters['order_id']);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
            $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   //get status code
            $result=curl_exec ($ch);
            curl_close ($ch);
        return $response = json_decode($result);
    }



$parameter = array('path' =>'https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges','token'=>$_POST['stripeToken'],'amount'=>5986,'order_id'=>99999);

$this->curl_stripe($parameters)
```